# OpenGl - calculate normal in cube

Tags: opengl

i need calculate normal of 6 faces from cube.
The cube is moved with keys, so, as the position of cube i need know normal face.

There any method that help this calculation??

Comment: if you need it only for cube faces, you could manually write the normals, for example west side of cube = -1,0,0, east side = 1,0,0, north side = 0,-1,0, south side = 0,1,0, top side = 0,0,-1, bottom side = 0,0,1, if i remember correctly.

Comment: This only works if the sides are aligned with the coordinate system.

Comment: oh yeah, i didnt think anyone would create a cube thats rotated with something else than glRotatef()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you maintain the relationship between faces you can calculate one and then get all the others using transformations.  Or you can just calculate all six individually.

The easiest way to do it is to use the [cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two edge vectors and normalize the result to get a unit vector in 3D.

Pick any cube surface that has points (1, 2, 3, 4) numbered in such a way that if you look down the unit vector normal to the face the numbers run in the counterclockwise direction.

Calculate the vectors between points 1 and 2:

[image]

Same for a vector running from point 1 to point 4.

Cross the first vector into the second, normalize it, and that's your unit vector.

Comment: Cross-product?  What do you know about vectors?

Comment: i know what is vectores and cross-product, but i dont know in practice how it this is made, thanks for the help